# unorganized table values and changing places Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a get data method which contains the Somme of Benefices per establissment from the backend API, I have stored them in a table and when I console this table and after each browser refresh, all my data changes position , I don't know why and how can I fix it

**MY METHOD**

```js
 xdata: any = [];
  rows: any = []
  getdata() {
    this.cr.getdata().subscribe(data => {
  this.rows = data
  for (let i of this.rows) {
    
    //this.etab=[]
    this.etab.push(i['etabName'])
    
    //this.users=[]
    this.users.push(i['users'].length)
    this.cr.getBenificeByet(i['id']).subscribe(res => {this.xdata=res;console.log(this.xdata) })

    this.chart1();
    this.chart2();
     
  }
}
)
  }
```

**first display of the data console**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KzWS.png)

**second display of the data console**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbQAK.png)

Comment: It's not super obvious what's going on here, but the first thing you need to check is if `data` from `this.cr.getdata().subscribe(data` is always in the same order. The logs aren't in the same order, because you're probably logging in an asynchronous callback.

Comment: I have checked it and always in the same order.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense that you assign to the field `xdata` if that happens multiple times. Also in the `getBenificeByet` callback/subscribe. The responses to `getBenificeByet` will likely come in a different order than the calls are made.